# Getting data from local caching in Inertia.js

Tags: vue.js, inertiajs

Comming from here: [Inertia Local State Caching](https://inertiajs.com/local-state-caching)

How do I get data from my local state caching on a new page?

Example:

```
  remember: ['cart'],

  data() {
    return {
      sending: false,
      cart: {
        amount: 1,
        value: 50,
        deliverance_date: null,
        send_by_email: true,
        send_by_phone: false,
      },
       currency: 'EUR',
    };
  },
```

The link above does not cover how to access the `remembered data`.

How can I access `cart` data on the next/new page?